# Daily Reminders (notifications) not sending randomized messages even though im using .randomElement() method (Swift) 2019/2020

Tags: swift, xcode

I made a daily reminders app that partially works, in that it sends daily reminders (notifications) every day at the specified time I give it. However, it does not randomize the messages that it sends. The user gets the same exact message every single day, despite the fact that I am using the .randomElements() method as per the following line: content.body = reminders.randomElement()!

Is there any reason why the messages aren't randomizing/how I can fix it?

Thank you in advance.

```
    var reminders = ["message 1", "message 2", "message 3"]

    @IBAction func setReminder(_ sender: Any) {


        label.text = "Reminders: Set. Daily 4:00 p.m."


        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Facts, tips, and tricks to help you quit:"
        content.body = reminders.randomElement()!
        reminders.shuffle()
        content.sound = .default
        content.userInfo = ["value": "Data with local notification"]

        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        //let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        //let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
        //let second = calendar.component(.second, from: date)

        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = 16
        dateComponents.minute = 0
        dateComponents.second = 0
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

        //let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(i) * 5, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "reminder", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the same text every time is that the random element function is being executed just once, when you set the body, not every time the alert is sent. The body of the notification is a `String` that gets stored by the system, and the system can't store the instruction `select a random string from these three`

If you want the alert to be random every day you would have to create a notification for each day (maybe up to a week or two?), and set the body of each notification to one of the random strings.

Comment: So it can only for done for a week or two (not in an infinite loop)?

Comment: You can do infinite notifications if you want the same exact alert every time, or you can set different notifications for each day with a different message, but you'll have to provide the message for each day. I'm also pretty sure there's a limit of how many notifications you can schedule.